# data.table and Auto-complete Compatibility

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

Compare this behaviour,

```
df <- data.frame(a11111 = rnorm(5,0), b11111= rnorm(5,0))
df$a # pressing tab at this instance auto-completes a11111
df$a # hitting return at this instance returns the value for a11111
```

with this behaviour:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,a # pressing tab at this instance does not auto-complete a11111
dt[,a # pressing return at this instance returns an 'object not found' error
dt$a  # behaves like how it does for the data frame
```

I assume the return works because `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`? However, I don't understand the auto-complete behaviour. Since the `data.table` syntax is based on `[`, is it practical and/or possible for `dt[,a <tab/return>` to work something like `dt$a<tab/return>`?

I'm running Rstudio 0.97.551 with R version 3.0.1 on Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: I'd love to have this feature if it were possible! (unfortunately I don't think it is)

Comment: @eddi, no responses yet but if you can, I'd like to know why you don't think so.

Comment: It's just that afaik R doesn't export this kind of functionality. If this is not true though and if someone knows how to do this, I'd love to hear more details.

Comment: What IDE/OS are you using? @eddi RStudio does this (but not for the example as the OP points out - it gives tab-complete for functions (as arguably it should).

Comment: @SimonO101, added that information to the question.

Comment: Already asked to RStudio w/o response.... http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/4258-code-completion-inside-functions I also just found [this](https://rforanalytics.wordpress.com/useful-links-for-r/code-enhancers-for-r/)

Comment: Thanks @Michele - the support link seems to be broken, this is probably the right one - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200653083-Code-Completion-inside-functions

Comment: @Codoremifa the problem is RStudio did something weird to the help page... all the old links now are broken if you are **not** logged in. In the original post I don't have that strange picture... :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is currently possible in the latest dev version of RStudio.
In case of any issues in terms of data.table auto-complete you may try post comment in this [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/984).

Comment: Don't think this is a dev feature anymore?